# What would we violate if we use principal component analysis on datasets containing only dummy variables?

Tags: pca, categorical-encoding

I have 23 dummy variables that are generated through a multiple-answer question. Respondents could choose more than one option. I ran a PCA and could see meaningful components emerging. I then calculated the values of components as the new variables (they are 7); varimax is used for rotation. I however wonder if there is any issue with respect to the required assumptions or the nature of data that would question the credibility of this practice? I am not interested in workarounds.

I have 23 dummies resulting from a multiple-answer question, answered by 96 cases. PCA with varimax rotation generated 7 PCs. the loadings on the variables/options make almost perfect sense (for loadings above 0.35), for instance, PC1 clearly is loaded by the variables that are about the environment, PC2 is loaded by variables that are about social justice, etc etc. what could be wrong statistically?

I also ran an optimal scaling in multiple correspondence analysis in SPSS. for this you need to change your dummies from 0-1 to 1-2 (categorical). determining 3 dimensions (instead of 2 or 7), the three dimensions here correspond well with the three of the seven dimensions found in normal pca. dummies seem to be functioning like scale variables when using normal pca. so again, assuming that we can make a sensible interpretation, what statistical/mathematical assumption could be violated by running pca on dummies?

Comment: May, but better look into multiple correspondence analysis!

Comment: correspondence analysis is irrelevant to my question.

Comment: please open up my question. I checked all the suggested links. They are not answering my question. I am not looking for a workaround solution. my question is simple! what would be wrong with a normal PCA used with a set of data that are ALL dummy variables. 
Please avoid misunderstanding the questions and thus closing them; this not ethical and results in frustrations.

Comment: dummy variables are used often in regressions, and a cpa regression base then should be fine, or am i missing something?

Comment: Please then tell us what is your goal, what do you want to achieve with pca on indicators? Also more context&details, like what are te survey questions about, sample size, ...

Comment: what do we use PCA for? detecting the underlying variables. that is my main purpose.

Comment: OK, I will reopen, but for this to be answerable you really need to add more context&details, like the one you gave in another posts, which I will now close as a dup of this one!