# what could be wrong with a Principal Component analysis that uses regression on dummy variables? (I am not looking for workarounds)

Tags: pca, categorical-encoding

I have already checked the suggested links and they do not answer my questions; my question is simple and does not need to be reinterpreted. So please do not close the question until it receives its proper answer. What would question the credibility of a PCA used on dummy variables that generate components as the underlying continuous variables? I do not care if there are specific methods like tetrachoric PCA etc
There is no mixture of variables. they are all dichotomous (0,1).

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! To which suggested links are you referring?

Comment: Suppose we have dichotomous data involving two variables has_at_least_one_brother and has_at_least_one_sister, where 1 means a subject has at least brother/sister and 0 means a subject doesn't have a brother/sister. Now suppose that the first PC has loadings of 0.5 for each category. PCs are opportunities to define and interpret mixtures of measurements, how would *you* interpret that scenario? The inability to make a sensible interpretation of PC loadings is one objection to the use of dichotomous variables in PCA analysis.

Comment: good point about a scenario which I am not sure how exceptional that can be. but in my case, the issue is not making sensible interpretations; because the interpretation of the PCs is sensible. I have 23 dummies resulting from a multiple-answer question, answered by 96 cases. PCA with varimax rotation generated 7 PCs. the loadings on the variables/options make almost perfect sense (for loadings above 0.35), for instance, PC1 clearly is loaded by the variables that are about the environment, PC2 is loaded by variables that are about social justice, etc etc. what could be wrong statistically?

Comment: I just also ran an optimal scaling in multiple correspondence analysis in SPSS. for this you need to change your dummies from 0-1 to 1-2 (categorical). determining 3 dimensions (instead of 2 or 7), the three dimensions here correspond well with the three of the seven dimensions found in normal pca. dummies seem to be functioning like scale variables when using normal pca. so again, assuming that we can make a sensible interpretation, what statistical/mathematical assumption could be violated by running pca on dummies?

Comment: If you are of the opinion that "interpretation of PCs is sensible" I'm unclear on why you are asking for help.

Comment: @Dave: He is referring to https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/572536/what-would-we-violate-if-we-use-principal-component-analysis-on-datasets-contain

Comment: @FrankHarrell - Once again: what status or mathematical assumptions underpinning PCA and any associated rotation may be violated if we only apply to dummy variables?